# Apache Yarn: yarn node -list, returning 0 nodes

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

I installed Hadoop in my mac book pro. I started yarn using ./start-yarn command but when i do a **yarn node -list**, its returning 0

My plan is to submit a flink job to Yarn cluster. Initially I thought since there are no jobs submitted, yarn node -list returning 0 is not a problem and so i went ahead and submitted a flink job.

Any help is greatly appreciated
There i am getting the following error.

*Caused by: org.apache.flink.configuration.IllegalConfigurationException: The number of requested virtual cores for application master 1 exceeds the maximum number of virtual cores 0 available in the Yarn Cluster.
at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor.isReadyForDeployment(YarnClusterDescriptor.java:335)
at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor.deployInternal(YarnClusterDescriptor.java:564)*

I am trying to submit a flink job.